# iOS - Where to resize UITableView in order to fit content when created in a custom View and not ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm facing an issue while working on `UITableView`. I am working with Google Map iOS SDK, and I created a custom View in order to implement my own `Marker Info Window`.

So I added the `UITableView` in my `UIView`, but I don't know where to resize it so that it fits its content.

I have set my `tableViewHeightConstraint`, and now I want it to fit the content of the tableView.

Code like this :

```
self.tableViewHeightConstraint = self.tableView.contentSize.height
```

I don't know where in a custom `UIView` I can do it, I don't have `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad` method.

And if I call it in the View's init method, it will probably be called too early, while its content isn't drawn yet.

**EDIT:**

Something like this ?

```
-(void) layoutSubviews {
    self.heightTableView.constant = self.tableViewRisk.contentSize.height;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try implementing the code `self.tableViewHeightConstraint = self.tableView.contentSize.height` in the views `layoutSubviews()` function

Comment: Yup you can use like how you have edited in the answer but add [super layoutSubviews] too before self.heightTableView.constant = self.tableViewRisk.contentSize.height;

Comment: Can I resize the UIView containing my UITableView too ?

Comment: Yup you can resize the UIView too. You can also do that in the viewcontroller where you are using that view.

Answer (score 0):

Add an key value observer on your tableview's contentSize property

```
[self.tableViewRisk addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:nil context:nil];
```

And add the following method

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context {
if (object == self.tableViewRisk && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentSize"]) {
    self.heightTableView.constant = self.tableViewRisk.contentSize.height;
} }
```

This will ensure that once the tableview is done reloading the content this code will update tableview's height constraint